# XSLT Can't Read an Excel XML File?

Tags: excel, xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT / XPath to browse some of the XML files you get when you unzip an Excel file. I found a "relationships" file *workbook.xml.rels* that I don't seem to be able to read, using code similar to that which successfully read the *workbook.xml* file.

Here's some of the *workbook.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
    ...
    <sheets>
        <sheet name="Sheet1"
               sheetId="2"
               r:id="rId1"/>
        <sheet name="Test Sheet"
               sheetId="1"
               r:id="rId2"/>
    </sheets>
    ...
</workbook>
```

Here's the *workbook.xml.rels* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3"
             Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme"
                  Target="theme/theme1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2"
                  Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet"
                  Target="worksheets/sheet2.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1"
                  Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet"
                  Target="worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId5"
                  Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings"
                  Target="sharedStrings.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4"
                  Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles"
                  Target="styles.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

Here's some of the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- greeting.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet
    ... 
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="baseDir"       select="replace(document-uri(.), '(.*[\\/]xl).*', '$1/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="workbook"      select="concat($baseDir, 'workbook.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="theSheetId" select="doc($workbook)/workbook/sheets/sheet[matches(@name, 'Test Sheet')]/@r:id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="workbook_rels" select="concat($baseDir, '_rels/workbook.xml.rels')"/>

    <!-- code to read workbook.xml.rels -->
    <xsl:variable name="theSheet"     select="doc($workbook_rels)/Relationships/Relationship[matches(@Id, $theSheetId)]/@Target"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;baseDir       = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$baseDir"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;workbook      = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$workbook"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;workbook_rels = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$workbook_rels"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;theSheetId    = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$theSheetId"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;theSheet      = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$theSheet"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;end</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output:

```
baseDir         = file:/C:/Training/sandbox/conv_/xl/
workbook        = file:/C:/Training/sandbox/conv_/xl/workbook.xml
workbook_rels   = file:/C:/Training/sandbox/conv_/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
theSheetId      = rId2
theSheet        = **<I get nothing here>**
end
```

You can see that 'theSheetID' variable is correctly set when reading *workbook.xml*. But when I use that variable to get the corresponding Target value into 'theSheet' variable from *workbook.xml.rels*, I get nothing. I tried replacing the matches expression with just a number but I still get nothing. Is there a problem from reading this type of file?

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a reproducible  example, not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `matches` and `replace` suggests you are using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor and that way XSLT 2 or 3 where you can certainly declare `xpath-default-namespace`, you just have to understand you have to change that in the sections that deal with elements from a different namespace e.g. `<xsl:variable name="theSheet" select="doc($workbook_rels)/Relationships/Relationship[matches(@Id, $theSheetId)]/@Target" xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"/>`.

Given the samples I would rather use a key `<xsl:key name="rel" match="Relationships/Relationship" use="@Id" xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"/>` and then use `<xsl:variable name="theSheet" select="key('rel,$theSheetId, doc($workbook_rels))/@Target"/>` but the use of `xpath-default-namespace` to declare the relevant namespace when selecting elements from a particular document is probably what is missing in your XSLT.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I suspected it had something to do with namespaces, but at my newbie level I didn't know quite how to address it.
I'll also study up on the use of keys.